# Customize word ribbon bar in office 365

Tags: ms-word, office365, word-addins

I have been working to add icon group to word ribbon bar but I can not customize it as I want. For an example when I add 3 buttons, it will appear as horizontal direction. But when I add 4 buttons one icon will appear as usual but other three as small icons for vertical direction. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: I'm sorry to bring you the bad news again, see my answer below. I looked into the specs for you and apparently there is no option to block the group from collapsing when using more than three controls, buttons in your case. If I get the chance I'll drop the request at the PG.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell the Manifest specifications do not allow you to set a fixed icon format or option to stop the group from collapsing the icons as you see when you use more than three buttons in your group.

The manifest specifications require you to that each icon must have three Images elements, one for each of the three mandatory sizes:

- 16x16
- 32x32
- 80x80

https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/manifest/resources.md#images

So without the option in the manifest to block the group from collapsing it is managed by Office and it seems you don't have any say in this (for now). Let the Program Group know you need a fixed size option, they appreciate your feedback.

Adding button specifications:

https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/manifest/control.md

Comment: Thank for the reply. Actually I have been working on word add-in development since few month but I got lot of problems in the API. Its better if Microsoft programmers can fix those problems

Comment: Do you know where should I drop a request for Microsoft?

Comment: I agree, MS is eager to hear your issues. I think your best option is UserVoice, this is actively monitored by the PG: https://officespdev.uservoice.com